# How can I print from 1 to 10 in the QGIS Plugin? ( not at once )

Tags: python, logging, pyqt, qgis

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage(str(i), tag="Validating", level=QgsMessageLog.INFO)
    time.sleep(1)
```

QGIS will wait for the plugin to finish. ( 123456789 )

It is bring to me result after finished work.

So i can't see step by step logging at QGIS. ( 1... 2... 3... 4... ... 9 )

I would like to see it printed each time it is executed.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use `time.sleep()` in the main thread of the GUI, that function is block the execution of the GUI so you get that behavior, in your particular case you can use `QTimeLine`:

```
def onframeChanged(val):
    msg = str(val)
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage(msg, tag="Validating", level=QgsMessageLog.INFO)

n = 9
self.timeline = QtCore.QTimeLine(n*1000)
self.timeline.setFrameRange(0, n)
self.timeline.frameChanged.connect(onframeChanged)
self.timeline.finished.connect(self.timeline.deleteLater)
self.timeline.start()
```

---

If you want the task to run periodically you can use `QTimer`:

```
def onTimeout():
    msg = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString()
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage(msg, tag="Validating", level=QgsMessageLog.INFO)

self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(interval=1000)
self.timer.timeout.connect(onTimeout)

self.timer.start()
```

Comment: how can i  pass parameter at self.timeline.frameChanged.connect(onframeChanged) ??

Comment: @윤현구 you can use `functools.partial()`: `from functools import partial` `...`  `self.timeline.frameChanged.connect(partial(onframeChanged, some_argument))`  and `def onframeChanged(some_argument, val):`